# QDomElement clear function

Tags: c++, qt

**I. What do I have**

In header file I have this:

```
QDomDocument *domDocument;
QDomElement *tagBase;
QDomElement *tagIr;
```

1) In the code I add elements:

```
tagBase = new QDomElement(domDocument->createElement("base"));
tagBase->setAttribute("version", "1.0");
domDocument->appendChild(*tagBase);

tagIr = new QDomElement(domDocument->createElement("ir"));
tagBase->appendChild(*tagIr);
```

2) Then I'm gonna let user add some more elements via QTableWidget with some attributes. In code It would be:

```
QDomElement tag = domDocument->createElement("tag");
tagIr->appendChild(tag);
```

3) Then I save this. The result is XML file:

```
<base version="1.0">
    <ir>
        <tag Маска="d" Имя тега="b" Тип тега="c" Смещение="e" № регистра="a"/>
        <tag Маска="" Имя тега="" Тип тега="" Смещение="" № регистра="f"/>
        <tag Маска="" Имя тега="" Тип тега="" Смещение="" № регистра=""/>
        <tag Маска="" Имя тега="" Тип тега="" Смещение="" № регистра=""/>
    </ir>
</base>
```

**II. What do I want**

I want to prepare my *domDocument* to use it again.
For this I use:

```
domDocument->clear();
```

1) I bit afraid of loosing memory of elements from the I.1) because after using this function there are no elements in the *domDocument* and I don't know if they were deleted properly.

2) If they were deleted properly can I use code I.1) again?

3) And 1 more question. I guess when I delete *domDocument* all the elements are deleted properly (include elements from the I.1)?

Comment: void QDomNode::clear()
"Converts the node into a null node; if it was not a null node before, its type and contents are deleted." From Qt documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I read it too. So it means that after void QDomNode::clear() pointers tagBase and tagIr will be = nullptr?

Comment: Your debugger can answer that question.